# How to get array values certain condition

Tags: php, arrays

There is something I want to ask to take the array value based on ***the biggest score*** in score keys and ***the smallest strlen*** in word keys, this sample array:

```
<?php
$data = array(
  '0' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titiek'),
  '1' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titik'),
  '2' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titie'),
  '3' => array('score' => '3','word' => 'tuatuka'),
  '4' => array('score' => '3','word' => 'titiks'),
);
$result = //do something??
print_r($result);
?>
```

let we see in $data array, condition the biggest score and the smallest strlen we have $data[1] and $data[2], right? but, I need the first queue. the result `print_r($result)` is a:

```
Array ( [score] => 4 [word] => titik )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `usort` to sort your array by `score` and then word length, and then your desired result will be in `$data[0]`. Note that we rank equal word lengths higher so that we return the first one of the shortest length that we see in the array.

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) {
    if ($a['score'] == $b['score'])
        return (strlen($a['word']) >= strlen($b['word'])) ? 1 : -1;
    else
        return $b['score'] - $a['score'];
});
print_r($data[0]);
```

An alternate method (not relying on `usort` behaviour) is to find the maximum score and then process the array looking for the first, shortest string with that score:

```
$max_score = max(array_column($data, 'score'));
$minlength = PHP_INT_MAX;
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if ($value['score'] != $max_score) continue;
    if (strlen($value['word']) < $minlength) {
        $minlength = strlen($value['word']);
        $index = $key;
    }
}
print_r($data[$index]);
```

Output (same for both):

```
Array ( 
    [score] => 4
    [word] => titik
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/WIas7)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_reduce](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) and by using ">=" "<=" it will keep the previous value

```
$result = array_reduce($data, function ($previous, $current) {
  return $previous['score'] >= $current['score'] && strlen($previous['word']) <= strlen($current['word']) ? $previous : $current;
});

var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can find it:

```
$data = array(
  '0' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titiek'),
  '1' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titik'),
  '2' => array('score' => '4','word' => 'titie'),
  '3' => array('score' => '3','word' => 'tuatuka'),
  '4' => array('score' => '3','word' => 'titiks'),
);
$maxScore = 0; $minLen = 0;
foreach($data as $key => $arr) {
  $score = $arr['score'];
  $len = strlen($arr['word']);
  if($score > $maxScore) {
      $maxKey = $key;
      $minLen = $len;
      $maxScore = $score;
    } else if ($score == $maxScore && $len < $minLen) {
      $maxKey = $key;
      $minLen = $len;
    }
}
var_dump($data[$maxKey]);
```

I have used var_dump to show the result. **$data[$maxKey]** is the required result.